# How can I setup page-specific css files in rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails to assist me in creating a static website. I have one controller `pages`. It has 4 action-view pairs: `home`, `team`, `work`, and `contact`.

Rails has created `pages.css.scss` for me, but there are elements in each of these pages that have the same name (i.e. class="container" or class="wrapper"), but have varying properties throughout the different pages.

What is the best practice for creating SASS stylesheets that are only applied to specific pages.

One method that I've read of is to use `content_for`, in which I create stylesheets for each of these pages, and use `content_for` to include them in the header of each individual page. Are there any negatives associated with this? The only thing I can think of is the fact that I have to tell rails to precompile every one of the page-specific .scss files, which is tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You need `content_for` and need to restrict loading all tree directory to only those files which are common all over your app.

Comment: If you'd like me to take a closer look in the next 30 min, click to my profile and connect with me on video chat.

Comment: However, this still doesn't get around having to add every single css.scss file to the precompile list. Is there a method that gets around this?

Answer (score 0):

you can just put the `<style></style>` directly on the view file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).